# Babel js. Get the first child of a node. Following the visitor pattern

Tags: javascript, babeljs, visitor-pattern

I need to get the first child of the "Program" node. I'm following the visitor pattern.

```
    let out2 = babel.transform(tc1, { plugins: [
    {
        visitor: {
            Program(path) {
                console.log(path);
                // path.insertBefore(decorators[d]);

            }
        }
    }]});
```

note that `decorators[d]` contains a node. The reason why I'm trying to get the first child is because the `insertBefore` line doesn't seem to work. It throws this error.

```
TypeError: unknown: Cannot read property 'isExpressionStatement' of null
```

so I want to try to execute the line on the child of the node.

---

Things I've tried:

```
path.children[0];
```

and

```
path.node.right;
```

and

```
path.traverse({
    Program(p2) {

    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
path.get("body.0");
```

But I've used this the most:

```
path.traverse(
{
    TypeOfNode(path){ }
})
```

---

I've also tried inserting into this and it worked:

```
path.node.body
```

which is an array of nodes. For example if you want to insert a node before the array (using the javascript `unshift` function) you would do:

```
path.node.body.unshift(node);
```